# fileUploadListener: prime faces fileUploadListener doesn't invoke the method

Tags: file-upload

I'm developing a web application with PrimeFaces 4.0.RC1 and i have problem with file upload,

exactly with the fileUploadListener; this listener doesn't invoke the method "handleFileUpload".

When i try to invoke this method with commandButton: the action in the commandButton work fine;

this is a pert of my web.xml:

```
<!-- Filter for the JSF uploder -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name>
    <param-value>commons</param-value>
</context-param>
<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

this my xhtml page:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p:growl id="kpiUploadNote" showDetail="true" sticky="true" />

<!-- Test with advanced fileUpload -->
<p:fileUpload
    fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadController.handleFileUpload}"
    mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="false" sizeLimit="100000"
    update="kpiUploadNote" fileLimit="3" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(csv|xlsx)$/" />

<!-- Test with commandButton to test the bean -->
<p:commandButton action="#{fileUploadController.handleFileUpload}"
    update="kpiUploadNote" ajax="false" />
</h:form>
```

this my ManagedBean:

```
@Scope
@ManagedBean(name = "fileUploadController")
public class FileUploadController {
    public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
    System.out.println("calling file upload...");
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Succesful",        event.getFile().getFileName() + " is uploaded.");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }

public void handleFileUpload() {
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Succesful", " is uploaded.");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }
}
```

This my first Question in stack overflow  and i hope you help me :),

Comment: It's so simple :D ,

When you using pretty faces add FORWARD to your filter mapping in the web.xml ;)

    <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
  <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
  <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
 </filter-mapping>

i hope this help someone :D